# Magento-2.2.7 "JQMIGRATE: jQuery.attrFn is deprecated" error in console

Tags: jquery, magento2.2.7, console, jqmigrate

This error occurs in browser console once in every 6-8 times and jQuery doesn't work a all on the page. when I reload the page everything works fine.

[image]

Comment: Are you solve this?

Comment: @ManoM Nops. No luck so far.